# How can I change a value on my html template from a class?

Tags: php, oop

This is my first attempt with OOP. I want to modify some values from a class, but I can't figure out how to do that from a different file. If I try to do that from where I have the class is working.

So, all I want is basic html page where i can modify some values.

HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

My class.php

```
<?php

class show {

public function setTitle ($t) {
    $this->title = $t;
            }

public function seth1 ($h1) {
    $this->h1 = $h1;
            }

public function getTitle () {
    return $this->title;
            }
public function geth1 () {
    return $this->h1;
            }
public function render () {
        $s = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>";
$s .= "<title>";
$s .= $this->title;
$s .= "<title>";

$s .= "<h1>";
$s .= $this->h1;
$s .= "</h1>";


$s .= "<p>and so on</p>

    </body>
    </html>";
     echo $s;
 }
 }
 ?>
```

index.php

```
 <?php

 include dirname(__FILE__) . '/inc/class.php'; // the above example

 $s = new show;
 $s->setTitle('title');
 $s->seth1('h1');
 $s->render();
 ?>
```

This is just an example of what I'm trying to accomplish. All I get is a blank page...

Comment: Look at Dougs answer. Also where your object is named $s you can use: echo print_r($s) to show the current state of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Is it just me, or are you missing your call to $s->render() ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Actually, this 100% answers the problem as stated at the bottom of the original question

Comment: >i did forgot to write it in the example, but either way the result is the same : blank page - error log is empty

>and even test it with an online compiler ... same result

Comment: Are you getting a real blank result, or your HTML shell with an empty <title>, and <h1> tag?